# Wrong ip passed in the request from ScriptA to ScriptB

Tags: python, ip, cpanel, request-headers

I actually have 2 python scripts that should interact between each other.
Both of them are on the SAME server but each one of them has its own domain and its own dedicated IP assigned. The server used is a Centos server with WHM/Cpanel.

The problem is that when ScriptA sends a request to interact with ScriptB it passes the IP of the ScriptB in the request and for this reason the ScriptB refuses to interact (because we implemented a protection anti-hack method and the IP should match the domain providing a digital signature for that specific IP).

The problem is not directly related to the scripts because even creating a very basic test page or connecting via ssh from ScriptA account to ScriptB account... the ScriptB received its own IP in the request.

I need to understand how I can modify the setting on the server so the ScriptA will pass its own IP to the ScriptB.

Comment: if they're on the same machine, can't you use 127.0.0.1?

Comment: If i could change the ip passed i would have changed it already. anyway the ScriptB will not answer if the request is not received by the public ip assigned to the ScriptA.